# BASH file mass rename with counter

Tags: bash, rename

I want to rename all the files in a folder with `PREFIX+COUNTER+FILENAME`

for ex. 
input:

```
england.txt  
canada.txt  
france.txt
```

output:

```
CO_01_england.txt  
CO_02_canada.txt  
CO_03_france.txt
```

Comment: How do you want the numbers to be assigned?  At random?  Your example shows non-alphabetic, so I guess you don't care?

Comment: no ti should be sequential.. 01,02,03.. initial prefix is fixed (CO)

Comment: But you don't care if it's 01 - canada, 02 - france, 03 - england?  So it's evidently random which sequence the files are handled in.

Comment: yes. you're correct

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This does what you ask:

```
n=1; for f in *.txt; do mv "$f" "CO_$((n++))_$f"; done
```

#### How it works

- `n=1`

  This initializes the variable `n` to 1.
- `for f in *.txt; do`

  This starts a loop over all files in the current directory whose names end with `.txt`.
- `mv "$f" "CO_$((n++))_$f"`

  This renames the files to have the `CO_` prefix with `n` as the counter.  The `++` symbol tells bash to increment the variable `n`.
- `done`

  This signals the end of the loop.

#### Improvement

This version uses `printf` which allows greater control over how the number will be formatted:

```
n=1; for f in *.txt; do mv "$f" "$(printf "CO_%02i_%s" "$n" "$f")"; ((n++)); done
```

In particular, the `%02i` format will put a leading zero before the number when `n` is still in single digits.

Comment: Thank John! pretty much does what i want.  but the second version does not increment the counter, and simply rename like CO_01_england.txt , CO_01_france.txt

Comment: @user3148655 The incrementation was inside a subshell, so it didn't stick. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

With the `prename` utility found on Debian and derivatives or available on other systems by installing the Perl package [`Unicode::Tussle`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::Tussle):

```
prename 's ([^/]*\z) (sprintf("C0_%02d_%s", ++$n, $&))e' england.txt canada.txt france.txt
```

Explanation: for each argument, rename the base name (the longest suffix not containing a slash) to `C0_` followed by the counter value `$n` (incremented before use, starting at 0 before the first incrementation and use) formatted to two decimal digits, followed by `_`, followed by the original name. To rename all files with the `.txt` extension, with the numbering in lexicographic order:

```
prename 's ([^/]*\z) (sprintf("C0_%02d_%s", ++$n, $&))e' *.txt
```

With zsh, use the [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) function, and the [parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) `l` to pad the number:

```
autoload -U zmv
zmv '*.txt' '$f:h/C0_${(l:2::0:)$((++x))}_$f:t'
```